# Why is my pseudo element showing up in one HTML demo but not in my angular 5 app?

Tags: css, angular, angular5, pseudo-element

```
    .gallery.style2 > .forward, .gallery.style2 > .backward {
        text-decoration: none;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 5rem;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 2;
    }

        .gallery.style2 > .forward:before, .gallery.style2 > .backward:before {
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-transform: none !important;
        }

        .gallery.style2 > .forward:before, .gallery.style2 > .backward:before {
            display: block;
            top: calc(50% - 1.5rem);
            width: 4rem;
            height: 3rem;
            line-height: 1em;
            font-size: 3rem;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
        }

    .gallery.style2:hover > .forward, .gallery.style2:hover > .backward {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .gallery.style2 > .forward {
        right: 0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 15%, transparent);
    }

        .gallery.style2 > .forward:before {
            content: '\f105';
            right: 0;
        }

    .gallery.style2 > .backward {
        left: 0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 15%, transparent);
    }

        .gallery.style2 > .backward:before {
            content: '\f104';
            left: 0;
        }
```

I'm learning some Angular by doing the Tour of Heroes tutorial and I wanted to play around with some pretty CSS from HTML5UP.net. This is a snippet of the CSS for some pseudo elements (a forward arrow and a back arrow on a gallery-like element). [This](https://html5up.net/story) is the actual demo of the HTML and CSS, which works as intended on the 'Gallery' portion. However, once I imported all the CSS into my Angular project, the pseudo-elements won't show up.

Any idea how I can get them to work the way they do in the demo? Am I foolish for thinking they should work with Angular?

Comment: are globally importing the CSS styles or importing them into a component stylesheet?

Comment: can you post your `HTML` too? because we are coders not magicians :D It will help

Comment: I globally imported the CSS styles. After some digging, it turned out that there were some javascript files that were supposed to generate some elements for the gallery element that weren't properly imported. Once I imported them into my index.html instead of my app.component.html, everything worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I globally imported the CSS styles. After some digging, it turned out that there were some javascript files that were supposed to generate some elements for the gallery element that weren't properly imported. Once I imported them into my index.html instead of my app.component.html, everything worked flawlessly.